# django Model Forms customizing fields

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

I have created a model with some classes:

```
class Student(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    last_name = models.CharFIeld(max_length=40)
(...)
```

and in the same models.py file at the bottom I've added a class corresponding to one of my models so i can create a form:

```
class StudentForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Student
```

How do I customize form fields created via ModelForm class ? I was reading django Documentation and I can't understand overriding the default types part. 
For example, in documentation they say this will work:

```
class ArticleForm(ModelForm):
    pub_date = DateField(label='Publication date')

    class Meta:
        model = Article
```

but when i type my values it's not working. I can't define my label:

```
class StudentForm(ModelForm):
    name = CharField(label='New label')

    class Meta:
        model = Student
```

Do i have to create a file like forms.py with identical fields as in Model class and then customize them ? Is it possible to change single field css attributes like width, height using only Model Forms ?

Comment: Please specific what happen when you say it's not working. For example from your code you not indent a line after "class" define (line contain : name = ... ) that will made a syntax error.

Comment: not working is for example i can't use CharField alone i need to add models.CharField, but then the label is not changing because models.CharField dont have label attribute. The runserver command is hanging at Validating models... with no errors. And i forgot indendts writing my question here but not in project

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Field for form use a difference library to create a from. You need to import `django.forms` and use `form.XXX` for specific Field

```
from django import forms


class StudentForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Student

    subject = forms.CharField(label='New label')
```

Comment: from django import forms - that's what I was missing. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

In order to customize field in model form, you don't need to create it manually. Django model fields have special attributes:

- `verbose_name` (goes to label of the field)
- `help_text` (by default rendered as additional description below the field)

So, all you need is:

```
class Student(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(
        max_length=40,
        verbose_name="Student's Name", 
        help_text="Please tell me your name")  # Optional
    last_name = models.CharFIeld(max_length=40)
    ...
```

Then you don't need to do any customization in model form.

See: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#verbose-name