# How to change help text of a django form field?

Tags: django, django-forms

This is my model for a group message which extends another model `Message` which has some other fields like `text`, `time`, etc.

```py
class GroupMessage(Message):
    group = models.ForeignKey(Group, related_name='+')
```

Following is the form I've created for this model.

```py
class GroupForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = GroupMessage
```

How do I change help text of group field in my form? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you mean label? Here is the similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14027185/django-model-forms-customizing-fields - yet, it is not answered correctly!

Comment: See my answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24345173/667154

Comment: I've never done it.. but in fields.py I see something like `help_text`.. then try it.. `help_text='Your help message'`. Btw. You shouldn't use `_` for class name. `_` is for protected methods/variables.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

I got it working with following code.

```
class _GroupMessageForm(ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = GroupMessage


class GroupMessageForm(_GroupMessageForm):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(_GroupMessageForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['employees'].help_text = '<br/>Hold down "Control" to select more.'
```

Comment: For future reference, this is included right in the docs: [Field Options](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.Field.help_text)

Comment: Instead of using help_text in the form, I would add it to the definition of the field in the Model.  That way, it doesn't matter what form we use the field on.  `group = models.ForeignKey(Group, related_name='+', help_text='<br />Hold down "Control to select more.")`

Answer (score 74):

For **Django >= 1.6** ([docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/#overriding-the-default-fields)):

```
class GroupForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = GroupMessage
        help_texts = {
            'group': 'Group to which this message belongs to',
        }
```

Answer (score 8):

There are multiple ways to do it.

1) You can add help_text to definition of the field in the Model, as [Bobort](https://stackoverflow.com/users/603819/bobort) said in the comment above:

```
class GroupMessage(Message):
    group = models.ForeignKey(Group, related_name='+', help_text='Some text')
```

This way is useful if you want this help_text stay the same, no matter what ModelForm you use. For example you can create two ModelForm forms for GroupMessage model and they both will have help_text from this model.

2) You can override model field in form field like that:

```
class GroupForm(ModelForm):
    group = forms.ModelChoseField(label='Group', help_text='Some text')

    class Meta:
        model = GroupMessage
```

Such way is useful when you need to change not only help_text but for example label or queryset or type of field.

3) You can do it as [laffuste](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1297812/laffuste) above:

```
class GroupForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = GroupMessage
        help_texts = {
            'group': 'Group to which this message belongs to',
        }
```

This way is useful if you only want to change help_text for one or more fields.

4) And another way to do it is something like you did:

```
class GroupForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = GroupMessage

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(GroupForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['employees'].help_text = 'Some text'
```

But this solution needs small clarification. If you will use this form in template like that:

```
{% for field in form %}
    {{ field }}
    {{ field.help_text }}
{% endfor %}
```

It's fine. But for example in case:

```
{% for field in form.visible_fields %}
    {{ field }}
    {{ field.help_text }}
{% endfor %}
```

help_text will be empty, because help_text in BoundField was filled before you set it by yourself. So solution will be to add `self['employees'].help_text = 'Some text'` to `__init__` or to use `{{ field.field.help_text }}` in template.

This solution is useful in cases when you want to set help_text by some conditions, for example if specific argument was passed to form initialization or something else.

Hope it will help someone.

Comment: Thank you for the amazing and thorough answer!