# add help text for OneToOneField

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-admin

I want to add a `help_text` to a field in my admin create for a model. I already tried what is suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24344981/how-to-change-help-text-of-a-django-form-field).

models.py:

```
class Product(models.Model):
    name = ...
    ean = models.OneToOneField(EANCode, on_delete = models.CASCADE, help_text = "from model, not visible ...")
```

forms.py:

```
class ProductAdminForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = '__all__'
        help_texts = {"name": "this is visible", 
                      "ean": "this is not visible"}
```

So I can add a helptext to a `CharField` but not to a `OneToOneField`. Why?

Answer (score 0):

This would be a bit of a workaround, but you can change how the field names show up in the admin by using `verbose_name`

```
    ean = models.OneToOneField(EANCode, on_delete = models.CASCADE, verbose_name = "EAN - not visible")
```

Comment: nope, this changes nothing - it does also work everywhere BUT the OneToOneField.